# Ошибка при разворачивании дампа таблиц

Tags: mariadb

Не могу развернуть дамп.

-- Server version   10.3.36-MariaDB-0+deb10u2

Вот я такой командой  делаю дамп Сервер mariadb

`mysqldump -u*логин* -p*пароль* --no-create-info  --skip-add-drop-table --default-character-set=utf8 *ИмяБазы* *СписокТаблиц* > dump.sql`

Дамп создается. Но при попытке его запустить командой

`mysql -uлогин -p ИмяБазы < dump.sql`

пишет ошибку:

> ASCII '\0' appeared in the statement, but this is not allowed unless option --binary-mode is enabled and mysql is run in non-interactive mode. Set --binary-mode to 1 if ASCII '\0' is expected.

Включаю бинарный режим:

`mysql -u*логин* -p --binary-mode  *ИмяБазы* < dump.sql`

Пишет

```
Unknown command '\''
```

Я в тупике...

Comment: *Но при попытке его запустить* Как именно Вы его "запускаете" - нам предлагается угадать? И Вы указываете в строке запуска, что кодировка дампа - UTF8?

Comment: @Akina 
mysql -uлогин -p ИмяБазы < dump.sql

Comment: Угу... дамп в UTF8... а консоль небось в ANSI? так чему удивляться?

Comment: @Akina ДОбавил опцию --default-character-set=utf8
Теперь пишет 
ERROR 1136 (21S01) at line 23: Column count doesn't match value count at row 52

Comment: Ну посмотри глазками-то, что там в строке 52...

Comment: @Akina Дело, похоже, не в этом. Сделал дамп одной таблицы - чтоб открывался в редакторе. Вот что пишет: 
The file you opened has some invalid characters. If you continue editing this file you could corrupt this document.
You can also choose another character encoding and try again.

Comment: Опять те же грабли? Ну открыто же написано: *choose another character encoding*

Comment: @Akina Но не написано, на какую.

Comment: Ну попробуй вспомнить, какую кодировку ты указываешь при создании дампа...

Comment: @Akina utf8 Но при попытуке открыть файл редактор говорит, что кодировка UTF-8, но есть какие-то плохие симполы, которфе могут обвалить редактирование. Что-то происходит при создании дампа. Как забороть?

Comment: *при попытуке открыть файл редактор говорит, что кодировка UTF-8, но есть какие-то плохие симполы* Что за редактор-то такой?

Comment: Редактор XED. Пока задачу решил через phpMyAdmin, сбросив галочку "Збереження бінарних полів в шістнадцятковому вигляді (наприклад, "abc" стане 0x616263)". Сейчас поищу в доках, какая опция за это отвечает